# artifactory rest api fully qualified class search

Tags: repository, artifactory

Is there any way to use fully qualified class name to search from [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/)(similar to class-searth in Artifactory web UI). Based on this [Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) , i know i can use wildcard(*) and .class file extension like this:-

```
GET /api/search/archive?name=*Logger.class&repos=third-party-releases-local,repo1-cache
```

But i am looking for a way to use fully qualified class name similar to this:-

```
GET /api/search/archive?name=org.apache.log4j.Logger&repos=third-party-releases-local,repo1-cache
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Artifactory query language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) for this.
For example, a query for searching an archive item called `org/apache/log4j/Logger.class` in the jcenter-cache repository would be

```
items.find({
    "repo" : "jcenter-cache",
    "archive.entry.name":{"$eq":"Logger.class "}, 
    "archive.entry.path":{"$eq":"org/apache/log4j"}
})
```

The response would be

```
{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "jcenter-cache",
  "path" : "org/apache/log4j/com.springsource.org.apache.log4j/1.2.16",
  "name" : "com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.16.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 481202,
  "created" : "2015-12-30T20:57:36.305Z",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2010-08-04T13:18:06.000Z",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2015-12-30T20:57:36.354Z"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 1,
  "total" : 1
}
}
```

To run such a query using curl use the following when the query is inside a file names `aql.txt`

```
curl -H "content-type: text/plain" -uuser:password --data @aql.txt http://my-artifactory-host/api/search/aql
```

Comment: Can we use this query in Artifactory version 3.x? This doesn't seem to work in Artifactory 3.8.0

Comment: "archive.entries" is available in AQL since version [4.2.0](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+4.2)

Comment: That might be the reason for issue i have been facing. anyways thanks @drorb!!